# Blender 2.68 won’t start

Tags: blender

I just downloaded Blender 2.68 from [www.blender.org](http://www.blender.org) and 2.68.2 (Fedora 19) from [www.graphicall.org](http://www.graphicall.org).

I unpacked each and double-clicked the "Blender"- application. However, nothing happens. How can I run Blender?

I installed Blender 2.62 via software-center and it worked fine, but I really want to use version 2.68.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I’m still new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First you uninstall the Blender that you have installed from the Software Center. Then open your Terminal and enter the following:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install blender
```

That will install the latest Blender 2.68 in your Ubuntu.